# Disable button when datagrid is in edit mode

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpfdatagrid

I have usercontrol with a DataGrid binded to an observablecollection of items and two buttons: save changes and discard changes.

My problem is that when the user is editing a datagridrow the buttons remain clickable but aren't executed.

Is there a way to disable the buttons when the DataGrid is in edit mode?

I tried this code with no success:

```
<Button Content="SaveChanges" Command="{Binding Path=CmdSaveChanges}" 
                IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=MyDataGrid, Path=IsEditing, Converter={StaticResource InverseBooleanConverter}}" />
```

Comment: Why would you use an `InverseBooleanToVisibilityConverter` for the `IsEnabled` property? `IsEnabled` is `bool`, whereas `Visibility` is an `enum`. Do you see any binding error message in VS output window?

Comment: And DataGrid does also not have an `IsEditing` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are binding to an `IsEditing` property of an element named `MyDataGrid` which presumably is a DataGrid. However, DataGrid has no such property.

Although [DataGridCell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189426.aspx) has an [IsEditing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcell.isediting.aspx) property, there is no easy way to get the currently editing cell. [DataGrid.CurrentCell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.currentcell.aspx) will not give you the DataGridCell, but only a [DataGridCellInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcellinfo.aspx).

You are perhaps better of with attaching handlers to the DataGrid's [BeginningEdit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.beginningedit.aspx) and [CellEditEnding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.celleditending.aspx) events.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. However, I was expecting a solution where no code behind was needed as I'm following the MVVM pattern.